# Python requests not working on heroku as it worked on local host

Tags: python, flask, heroku, web-scraping, python-requests

I have an `api` running on [`heroku`](https://heroku.com). What my `api` does is fetches you results from [`amazon`](https://amazon.com) and puts it in the server for the respective request from [`flask`](https://pypi.org/project/flask). I am sorry because I have created that code for an [`organization`](https://botsuniverse.github.io) in github and cannot reveal its code. But I can show some code to explain the problem. You can assume that all the variables are defined and no known problem or error in the code.

###### My flask code:

```
# flask_cors are enabled for all the requests.
from api.amazon import amazon_search

@app.route( '/amazon', method=["GET"] )
def amazonSearch():
    q = request.args["query"]
    result = amazon_search(q) # It returns a JSON
    return result
```

##### The `api/amazon.py`:

```
def amazon_search(keyword):
    link = f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={keyword}&qid=1625886350&ref=sr_pg_2&page=1"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
    }
    page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup( page.content,"html.parser")
    # do some process and create a dict with variable `result`
    return result
```

I have already tried that, in my localhost and that works fine. But in `Heroku`, it does nor fetch any result. You can have a look at other working `APIS`:

- [IP](https://apibu.herokuapp.com/ip)
- [Random Password](https://apibu.herokuapp.com/random/string)
- [Github Search](https://apibu.herokuapp.com/github)
  You can see that all the above are Working, but the problem is with:
- [Amazon Search](https://apibu.herokuapp.com/amazon)
  That shows no error, but also fetches nothing. All the `APIs` are running on same server, and even `Github Search` is done by `requests` and `bs4`, but `Amazon Search` is not working.

###### The fetch results from the apibu.herokuapp.com:

```
// url: https://apibu.herokuapp.com/amazon?query=Apple
{
  link: "/amazon?query=Apple&page=1",
  page: 1,
  query: "Apple",
  results: [ ],
  status: 200
}
```

But, when I run the same code on my local host, the `result` list is filled with `50 dicts`.
My Specifications:

```
Python: 3.9.6
Windows 10 32bit
Firefox (latest version)
```

All other specification are the latest one.

Comment: I believe that Amazon are blocking requests coming from  Heroku :-(

Comment: What does parameter `q` in `amazon_search` function do? From Where  `keyword` variable comes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just misspelled those two words

Comment: @balderman how does amazon know that I am accessing from `Heroku`?? I think there is some problem with the `headers` because I got the same problem in my localhost and I added `headers` to the request and the problem was solved, but on heroku the same `headers` are not working.

Comment: @Parvat.R Was the variable misspelled in the real code also? Try using the headers provided in the article. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/scrap-amazon-products-and-pricing-data-with-heroku-deployment-cca778a99f8d

Comment: That is still not working

Comment: @Parvat.R - they know  it by the src IP

Comment: I heard like Amazon will block if more than 1 request per second. Also it will block almost all datacenter IPs and allow only Home IPs. But not sure 100%

Comment: I have a similar problem reading data from `https://api.nasdaq.com`. It works locally, but once ran on Heroku deployed app the `get` part hangs.

Comment: I am facing the same issue right now for nation stock exchange scraping . if anyone has figured out answer for this Question do tell me plz . Thanks